# Get results for multiple rows in MySQL table using view

Tags: mysql, view

I am still a student who learns MySQL. I have a database name "tech_lms" and a table "attendance" with 136 rows.

[image]

Using this table I want to get the percentage for students with "present" for "absent_present" column. So I have created a SQL view for this.

```
    CREATE VIEW eligible AS
    SELECT studentID,subID, 
      (COUNT(absent_present 
       WHERE absent_present="present")/COUNT(absent_present))*100 AS presentage 
FROM attendence;
```

But I can't get the expected results. There might be some errors in my code. If someone can help me, I would be appreciated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql have syntax error, try with below:

```
CREATE VIEW eligible AS
SELECT studentID,subID, 
  SUM(IF(absent_present='present',1,0))/COUNT(absent_present)*100 AS presentage 
 FROM attendence group by studentID;
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This saves my day. There Is one change in this code. That is the last ")" must be removed.